# Include adminLTE in Angular2 project

Tags: angular, templates, adminlte

I was trying to include the `adminlte` template in my angular project 2. I placed the `adminlte` folder inside `node_modules`, but when linking the `.js` and `.css` in the angular `index.html`, it does not find them, and I do not know why reason. Can anyone suggest me advice on this topic?

Attach code and error:

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOHpw.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JjBY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The answer it will not work that easy.

as per AdminLTE website "https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/documentation/index.html"

> Is there an integration guide for PHP frameworks such as Yii or Symfony?
>
> Short answer, no. However, there are forks and tutorials around the
>   web that provide info on how to integrate with many different
>   frameworks. There are even versions of AdminLTE that are integrated
>   with jQuery ajax, AngularJS and/or MVC5 ASP .NET.

so you can check this

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-admin-lte

but i think you can add the "bootstrap, dist, packages" inside "assets" folder in the project if you are using angular CLI

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by including the template means using AdminLTE.css file in your application.

In order to do this , you will need to import the .css file in your component.ts file as below :

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['bower_components/adminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css']
})
```

PS: make sure that the path is valid

Once the styleUrl is specified , we will be able to access the CSS selectors of Admin LTE or any other template in the dashboard.component.html file.

There are several ways to add CSS to your angular project , refer below link :
https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-the-ways-to-add-css-to-angular-2-components

An interesting way was to add through angular-cli as in below git hub link
https://github.com/ahmadalibaloch/Angular-AdminLTE

Answer (score 1):

I found an Angular 2 port of AdminLTE in github. You may want to have a look at this:

https://github.com/csotomon/Angular2-AdminLTE

Answer (score 0):

I was able to integrate AdminLte into my Angular project thanks to the [video on codingFriday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNomyjz0ewA). I was also able to add routing, and now i have the main pages of the site and admin pages with animations. I am new to web programming and my project has a lot of bad solutions (this is a coursework at my university), but maybe this will help someone get started.

https://github.com/paulrozhkin/tamagotchi-web-client

In short, the following steps should be taken (the source of steps is the [guide on github by codingFriday](https://github.com/cpvariyani/adminlte3-with-angular9)):

1. Install admin lte 3 in your project:

   ```
   npm install admin-lte@^3.0 --save
   ```
2. Choose dashboard and copy all links styles and scripts from dashboard to angular.json:

   For example, this is an updated angular.json file for dashboard 2.

   ```json
   "styles": [
     ...
     "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/docs_html/assets/css/adminlte.css"
   ],
   "scripts": [
     ...
     "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.js",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.js",
      "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.js",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/demo.js",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/raphael/raphael.js",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery-mapael/jquery.mapael.js",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery-mapael/maps/usa_states.js",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/chart.js/Chart.js",
     "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/pages/dashboard2.js"
   ]
   ```
3. Add a body class from the dashboard to your body.

   For dashboard 2 this could be:

   ```html
   <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed layout-navbar-fixed layout-footer-fixed">
   ```
4. Create a new component and copy the dashboard body from index to the template
5. Copy images to asset folder - to `\assets` from `\node_modules\admin-lte\dist\img`
6. Replace path images with `src="assets/<image-name>"`

---

Description of next steps to integration from me. I can’t guarantee that these are the best solutions and there may be better ones. When I added routing to the admin panel, I experienced the following problems:

1. The body class should not be applied to the rest, except for the admin panel.

   **Solution:**

   - Import `Renderer2` to admin-panel component.
   - In the `OnInit` admin-panel hook, this these classes are added using:

     ```js
     Renderer2.addClass (...)
     ```
   - In the `ngOnDestroy` admin-panel hook, this these classes are removed using:

     ```js
     Renderer2.removeClass(...)
     ```
2. After routing, js animation stops working.

   **Solution:**

   - Copy the `adminlte.js` to assets (also change path in angular.json) and replace:

     ```js
     $(window).on('load', function ()
     ```

     to

     ```js
     $( document ).ready(function()
     ```
   - Also, if you want to start dashboard animation (set map, chart data)  after routing, you must start it from the code behind on the dashboard panel.